# Как реализовать раскрытие программы поверх всего(как полноэкранный режим видео)

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу программу на C#, возникла потребность развернуть программу во весь экран, т.е. программа раскроется на весь экран и поверх всего, что включено.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `Пишу программу на шарпе` - а вы знали, что "шарп", это WinForms, WPF, Asp.net, Unity, Xamarin и уйма другого. Все они довольно прилично отличаются! И получается, что мы должны гадать что у вас?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ winform

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=winforms+во+весь+экран+

Comment: @qwabra вы не поняли вопроса. нужно убрать с виду все элементы управления, кроме самой формы(а именно сделать прогу поверх панели задач windows). Данное свойство `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` установлено, но не перекрывает. Увелечение самой формы в размерах, в самом коде, не дает результат. Форма выходит за рамки монитора вниз, но панель задач все равно поверх нее располагается

Comment: я не "в теме", но предполагаю, что к вопросу нужно 1) добавить метку winforms 2) версию среды разработки (winforms, с#, .NET, ...) 3) версию ОС 4) заглянуть сюда https://stackoverflow.com/q/7285386/4794368 и сюда https://stackoverflow.com/q/505167/4794368

Comment: помогает поверх сделать свойство `TopMost`, но тогда я другие окна не могу открыть по верх него.

Comment: Так а чего вы хотели, или окно первое (модальное) и остальные окна позади недоступны, или не пользуемся TopMost. :)

Comment: Я хотел совета услышать отразумных людей. А Гуглом я и сам умею пользоваться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как ни странно, но решение довольно простое, хотя и не очевидное. Если убрать рамку окна и максимизировать его, то получится именно тот эффект о котором вы говорите. С рамкой же, размер подгонится с учетом высоты панели задач (ширины, при вертикальном расположении).

Сразу замечу, что с включенной стандартной рамкой окна такой эффект получить штатными средствами Winforms не получится, возможно что-то получится выжать из WinAPI (Pinvoke), но в эту сторону я не копал, не было необходимости.

**Последовательность команд имеет значение**:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;//см. текст ниже.
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Кроме `FormBorderStyle.None`, можно использовать `FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow`, эффект аналогичен, но при этом сохраняется шапка с названием окна и, специфическая для данного стиля, кнопка закрытия окна (крестик).

Если окно уже максимизировано, то его необходимо переключить в другой режим: `Normal` или `Minimized`, так как размер окна пересчитывается только при изменении режима, но не при изменении стиля (включение/отключение рамки).

К недостаткам я бы отнес "мельтешение" при переходе в полный экран из максимизированного состояния. Это можно сгладить предварительной установкой размера окна равным его максимизированному размеру с рамкой.

К достоинствам - отсутствие необходимости использовать `TopMost` со всеми вытекающими проблемами.

Проверено на Win 7 и 10 как с автоматическим скрытием панели задач, так и без него.